# How to define a ReLU with TensorFlow custom_gradient?

Tags: tensorflow, relu

I'm practicing using TensorFlow's `custom_gradient` decorator and I tried to define a simple ReLU. One would think it would be as simple as defining the gradient to be `1` when `x > 0` and `0` otherwise. However, the following code does not yield the same gradients as a ReLU:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def relu(x):
    def grad(dy):
        return tf.cond(tf.reshape(x, []) > 0,
                       lambda: tf.cast(tf.reshape(1, dy.shape), tf.float32),
                       lambda: tf.cast(tf.reshape(0, dy.shape), tf.float32))
    return tf.nn.relu(x), grad
```

Can someone explain to me why this standard definition of ReLU's gradient does not yield the same performance as:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def relu(x):
    def grad(dy):
        return dy
    return tf.nn.relu(x), grad
```

Comment: Isn't proper ReLU f(x) = 0 if x<0; x if x >= 0?

Comment: Yes but I'm asking about the gradient. The derivative of what you just defined is f'(x) = 0 if x < 0 and f'(x) = 1 if x >= 0.